# Postgresql startup failure

Tags: postgresql, startup

I'm attempting to build a box via Fabric on Openstack. Part of the install involves installing and running PostgreSQL.

This command works fine:

```
$ sudo service postgresql initdb
```

This command fails:

```
$ sudo service postgresql start
```

Log output of failure shows no issues when I run this command:

```
$ cat /var/lib/pgsql/pgstartup.log
```

This command shows the following messages:

```
$ cat /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log/postgresql-Wed.log
```

> LOG:  could not open configuration file
>   "/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf": Permission denied
>       FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf

My user while executing these commands has the following groups:

```
vagrant, wheel
```

My user is in the `sudoers` list under `/etc/sudoers` with these permissions:

```
vagrant  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

perms on `pgsql`:

```
[root@integration ~]# ls -ltr /var/lib/pgsql/
total 12
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres 4096 Sep 13  2012 backups
-rw-------.  1 postgres postgres 1152 Jun 19 20:17 pgstartup.log
drwx------. 12 postgres postgres 4096 Jun 19 20:19 data
```

and sub dir `data`:

```
[root@integration ~]# ls -ltr /var/lib/pgsql/data/
total 76
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres     4 Jun 19 20:17 PG_VERSION
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres  4096 Jun 19 20:17 pg_twophase
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres  4096 Jun 19 20:17 pg_tblspc
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres  4096 Jun 19 20:17 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------. 4 postgres postgres  4096 Jun 19 20:17 pg_multixact
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16886 Jun 19 20:17 postgresql.conf
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres  1631 Jun 19 20:17 pg_ident.conf
drwx------. 3 postgres postgres  4096 Jun 19 20:17 pg_xlog
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres  4096 Jun 19 20:17 pg_subtrans
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres  4096 Jun 19 20:17 pg_clog
drwx------. 5 postgres postgres  4096 Jun 19 20:17 base
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres  4096 Jun 19 20:17 global
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres   241 Jun 19 20:17 pg_hba.conf
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres  4096 Jun 19 20:17 pg_log
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres    57 Jun 19 20:19 postmaster.opts
```

Comment: Cross posted on Unix & Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80066/postgresql-service-start-issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an selinux issue.
I disabled it and was well. Full config below.

For those of you that arent up on selinux (like me until today) the config can be found in:

```
 /etc/selinux/config
```

It can also be turned off temporarily like this:

```
echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
```

Full config

```
[root@integration selinux]# cat config 
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#   enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#   permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#   disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=enforcing
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#   targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#   strict - Full SELinux protection.
```

Comment: `setenforce 0` can also be used.